# Плагин Mathjax-latex для Wordpress. Как можно с помощью стилей поменять шрифт формул и размер?

Tags: css, wordpress, latex, mathjax

Решил попрактиковаться, создал сайт http://physicsfree.xyz/, встал вопрос, как менять стиль тех или иных элементов? Какой CSS файл нужно отредактировать для этого?

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете стандартный шаблон Wordpress twentysixteen, значит надо редактировать `CSS` файл в директории  wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/style.css.
Для точного определения из какого файла идут стили(если имеются другие файлы .css), используйте "консоль браузера" (F12)

Answer (score 0):

В настройках есть блок "дополнительный CSS".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или же (даже лучше) сделать [дочернюю тему](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B) и править что угодно.

Править оригинальные файлы тем не стоит. Тем более дефолтные темы - всё потеряется при обновлении.